# How to get the list of all test?

Tags: scala, sbt

In `sbt` when I type `testOnly` and after press the `tab` key, then I will get all available tests:

```
sbt:plugger> testOnly 
--                                       com.sweetsoft.detector.DetectorSpec      com.sweetsoft.sender.SenderMessageSpec
```

Is there a command to get all available test, instead press the `tab` key?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try executing `show test:definedTests` from sbt, which on my machine outputs

```
sbt:scala-213> show test:definedTests
[info] * Test example.RuleSpec : subclass(false, org.scalatest.Suite)
[info] * Test example.HelloSpec : subclass(false, org.scalatest.Suite)
```

Inspection of `definedTests` gives

```
inspect test:definedTests
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.TestDefinition]
[info] Description:
[info]  Provides the list of defined tests.
```

Comment: From the command line you can run `sbt "show test:definedTests"`.